# How can i figure out where a TFS path is mapped on any computer

Tags: java, visual-studio

I need to open files from Visual-Studio-TFS in order to work with them in my further **JAVA** code.
My Problem is that my tool has to work on multiple computers of different users. Not every User has TFS Mapped to the same location.

*How can i get the default path on the users computer where all his TFS Files are getting mapped to?*

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

> How can i get the default path on the users computer where all his TFS Files are getting mapped to?

TL;DR: You can't. There is no such *single* location.

Each combination of user and workstation can have zero or more workspaces mapped.

Eg. I have a different workspace mapping for each Team Project (this avoids hitting >100,000 files on a single mapping).

Eg. I have had multiple mappings of the same project on the same machine in different folders.

You will need to look at the list of mapped workspaces and see what server paths are mapped to which local folders and handle no or many mappings. With the .NET based client (as used by VS) there are methods in [`Microsoft.TeamFoundation.VersionControl.Client.Workstation`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.teamfoundation.versioncontrol.client.workstation(v=vs.120).aspx) that allow the mappings for the current user on the local system to be enumerated. I would assume the Java client has something similar.

PS. and if projects are using Git there is not even such a mapping to be enumerated (the "mapping" is a list of remotes in the local repository for that project).